# Windows reporting incorrect partition size

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, disk-space

I had a windows 10 and fedora linux dual boot I have since stopped using that installation and removed the partition with gnome disks as well as expanding the windows partition but now windows is reporting incorrect drive space. It says either 125GB used or 56GB used, 58GB total or 128GB total, and always 2GB free even though it used to be a 58GB partition with 2GB free but I have resized it to a 128GB partition. I have tried deleting all my restore pionts, running the system maintence troubleshooter and deleting the rogue trashbin folder all to no pravial. Even linux is reporting incorrect disk space.

**Update 1:**
I have ran `sudo ntfsresize --expand /dev/sda3` which gives me the following error:

```
ntfsresize v2021.8.22 (libntfs-3g) Sectors allocated to volume : old 129270032 current 247482360 difference 118212328 Clusters allocated to volume : old 16158754 current 30935295 difference 14776541 ERROR: The backup bootsector does not match the old bootsector
```

**Update 2:**
Managed to fix my issue by using a third party partition editor in windows.

Comment: Run `chkdsk` and report on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystems track their usable space independently from the device they're on. After growing a partition, you always need to use an fs-specific tool to expand the filesystem within, e.g. resize2fs. Some partitioning tools do this automatically – some others don't.

For NTFS, you'll need to run `ntfsresize --expand` on the partition.

You might also have some luck with using the native Windows `diskmgmt.msc` to slightly shrink the partition (by a few GB), then grow it again. Normally diskmgmt resizes the filesystem accordingly, but I'm not sure how it will react to trying to resize a mismatching one.

Comment: Does that mean from Linux I need to run
```ntfsresize --expand /dev/sda1``` or do I need to run it from Windows (which it doesn't autocomolete in powershell or command prompt) with the C:// drive in instead because last time I checked Linux couldn't write to NTFS filesystems

Comment: yes, `ntfsresize` is a Linux tool and takes /dev paths. Linux has had the ntfs-3g toolkit for writing to, and resizing, NTFS filesystems since about 2006.

Comment: @whatever edit the question and put that in the question itself, not in a comment

Comment: I have edited the question an put that in it